Unable to debug go programs using delve
Seeing this issue -- could not find rodata struct member when hitting debug in vscode
go version: 1.22.2
delve version: 1.22.1
workaround -
tried using dlv command from project root folder (dlv debug main.go), same issue
Reinstalled golang, vscode, delve manually but nothing helped
rolled back to older version of delve (1.21.2) but breakpoints are grayed out (Unable to locate file)
launch.json config is basic
 "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug go",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.go"
        }
    ]


I'm updating this answer to reflect the latest information from the relevant GitHub issue. Just like the commenter who solved this, my problem came from using an alternate clang version that was provided by LLVM. Their solution also worked for me and is better than my previous solution. You can set the CC and CXX environment variables in your launch.json:
        {
            "name": "Debug go",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.go",
            "env": {
                "CC": "/usr/bin/cc",
                "CXX": "/usr/bin/c++"
            }
        }

Or, set them globally via your shell profile or a similar method.
